# Not getting IPv6 address on Windows 10 when on wifi

Tags: windows, ipv6, intel

I have an IPv6 capable router/AP setup at home and when I connect to my main router via Ethernet my Windows 10 laptop gets an IPv6 address as expected (http://test-ipv6.com/ is all green, 10/10).

- When I connect to my AP via wifi my Windows 10 laptop doesn't receive an IPv6 address at all
- However if I connect to the same AP via wifi with my MacBook Air IPv6 works just fine

The only root cause I can think of is this:

- When I'm connecting to my main router I use an ASUS USB-Ethernet dongle (IPv6 is fine)
- When connecting via wifi my built-in Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 adapter is used

I have checked and IPv6 is enabled on the adapter, it's configured to obtain an IPv6 address automatically. The adapter's drivers are up-to-date.

Any idea what can be the cause of this? Thanks for all the inputs.

Comment: This site is for problems in business environments. What you do at home is off topic. Voting to migrate the question to [su].

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Well, it's my business laptop, it's just I've noticed this issue at home (haven't been to the "real" office for quite a while now). I've flagged my own question to move it elsewhere tho', fair point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found out that disabling/enabling my wifi adapter in Windows network at `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connections` fixes this.

More info [here](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/windows-10-no-ipv6-address-on-boot.390765/) - **note**: this might only be a temporary fix, but it works at least.